# Split multiple linq include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to split multiple linq include() methods for optimization query:

```
allRecords = context.Records.Where(r => r.versionId == version.id)
.Include(x => x.colors)
.Include(x => x.tags)
.Include(x => x.ranks)
.OrderBy(r => r.sortkey).ToList();
```

How can I optimize this query by breaking it down into simpler ones?
This request is too slow. It is necessary to increase its perfomance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. _If you don't need the `Include`, remove it or comment it out._

Comment: What means `Split` in this context?

Comment: How can I optimize this query by breaking it down into simpler ones?

Comment: The edit doesn't improve anything. If you want to retrieve colors, you want to retrieve colors. If you *don't* want them, don't use `Include()`

Comment: @MichaelKostiuchenko `How can you optimize this query by breaking it down into simpler ones?` doesn't explain anything. Executing *more* queries is *more* complex and can be N times slower than one query that retrieves what you want. Explain what the *actual* problem is

Comment: @MichaelKostiuchenko all functions in LINQ are just functions that take an IQueryable as a parameter and return a *new* one. That means you don't have to use all of them in a single chain. Each function returns a new IQueryable, which means you can store intermediate objects in variables, use conditional logic to call them etc.

Comment: `This request is too slow. It is necessary to increase its perfomance.` that's *completely* different. Do you have proper indexes? What do the tables look like? What does the *execution plan* look like? What does slow mean? Loading the same stuff in 2 or 3 queries will take 2 or 3 times longer

Comment: Please perform a SQL Trace and let us know what is the exact query being submitted to the database.

Comment: Are `VersionId` and `sortkey` covered by indexes? What about the fields involved in foreign key constraints? Do you really want to load all data for all those records at once or do you want specific fields only?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the includes conditional, using e.g. some boolean flags to do so:

```
var query = context.Records.Where(r => r.versionId == version.id);

if (includeColors) query = query.Include(x => x.colors);
if (includeTags  ) query = query.Include(x => x.tags);
if (includeRanks ) query = query.Include(x => x.ranks);

allRecords = query.OrderBy(r => r.sortkey).ToList();
```